# Problem with Breadcrumbs

Tags: magento-1.9

I am facing a weird problem in Magento 1.9. I am learning Magento and I have created two projects with the same design template. In my first project, I am getting breadcrumbs like Home > Bags > Ultimate Bag which is SEO friendly.

But on the other hand, I am getting something like Home > Shop > Bags > Ultimate Bag which is not SEO friendly.

It automatically adjusts to his parent category in the first project but not working in the second one I have the same data for both projects. Can anyone suggest What should I do to get Breadcrumbs like the first project?

Thanks